# Convert values inside a dict inside a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

For sake of reducing the question code and explanation let's say I have a dataFrame with multiple columns where one have dictionary as items.
The concrete question is: there's a fast way to convert all values inside every dict to float values?

```
q = [['asd','qwer',{'num':'1.3','num2':'2'}],
     ['www','qttr',{'num':'44.55','num2':'33'}]]
df = pd.DataFrame(q,columns=['a','b','data'])
```

I'm having:

|  | a | b | data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | asd | qwer | {'num': '1.3', 'num2': '2'} |
| 1 | www | qttr | {'num': '44.55', 'num2': '33'} |

what I would want

|  | a | b | data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | asd | qwer | {'num': 1.3, 'num2': 2} |
| 1 | www | qttr | {'num': 44.55, 'num2': 33} |

or

|  | a | b | num | num2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | asd | qwer | 1.3 | 2 |
| 1 | www | qttr | 44.55 | 33 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "quick" way with apply:

```
df['num'] = df['data'].apply(lambda x: float(x['num']))
```

This will have efficiency issues with big data frames.

Comment: I think you're missing the part where OP is looking for "a fast way to convert all values inside every dict to float values". The resulting column is still going to be `object` (in pandas 1.3.4, at least, dtype reduction with apply has changed many times over the versions)

Comment: Hi yesm this return `object` type but it's easy to correct using `float` to convert every value in the lambda function. I've edited to get this

Comment: Thanks for the answer! this was exactly (almost) what I wanted